# Two trigonometric and exponential integral

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, integration

You may view my related problem:
[A definite integral with trigonometric functions: $\int_{0}^{\pi/2} x^{2} \sqrt{\tan x} \sin(2x) \, \mathrm{d}x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/284933/a-hard-definite-integral-with-trignometric)

Show that :
$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}x\sqrt{\tan x}\text{e}^{2ix}\text{d}x=\frac{\pi \text{e}^{\frac{i\pi}{4}}}{8i}(\pi+2+2i\ln 2)$$
$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}x^2\sqrt{\tan x}\text{e}^{2ix}\text{d}x=\frac{\pi \text{e}^{\frac{i\pi}{4}}}{48i}(24i+(12+4i)\pi+5\pi^2+i(-4\pi+12(-2+\pi)\ln 2)-12\ln ^22)$$

Comment: @gauss115: Try to write $e^{2ix}=\cos(2x)+i\sin(2x)$ and then use the techniques from the problem you are referring to.