# prove this integral

Tags: integration

$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}x^2\sqrt{\tan{x}}\sin{2x}dx=\frac{\pi\sqrt{2}}{32}\left[\frac{5\pi^2}{6}+2\pi-2\pi\log{2}-4+4\log{2}-2\log^2{2}\right] $$

I think  this integral is very nice. and  I think this integral have nice methods?

my methods:let $\sqrt{\tan{x}}=t$

Comment: *prove this integral*... I can't, integrals are never *proven* (but some of them may be *computed*).

Comment: What happened to my comment?  I believe this is a duplicate of this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/284933/a-hard-definite-integral-with-trignometric/284952#284952

Comment: oh,Thank you,I can't found this question has been asked before.Thank you